# How do I add url links to WinWheel.js image slices?

Tags: url, canvas, hyperlink

How do I add a clickable link to any of the image slices so the user can click a slice to go to a url? Currently they can spin the wheel to get a random url choice. I got the random spin part working using “IF” but I got stuck figuring out the image slice click idea.

**I'm currently working at the top of page in an area calle**d:

//add code here?

```
if (clickedSegment) {
   clickedSegment.indicatedSegment = "Jane";
    window.location = "https://www.mikeloucas.com";
    theWheel.draw();
```

*and I have one url working due to the "clickedSegment" but it's active on all the slices and not what I need (I'm try to target **Jane**) so I'll keep at it unless some has an answer.*

Separately but related:
This is one of the image segments I'm trying to add add link to:

```
{'image' : 'https://mikeloucas.com/wheel/jane.png',  'text' : 'Jane'},
```

The original tutorial shows how to change the colour of a slice on click, but I’d like to go to a url instead.

Original Click Code: http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/docs/tut15_get_segment_clicked

The thing Im working on: https://codepen.io/mikeloucas/pen/qBarWoP

In my Codepen example I turned off the “IF” load url because its just in the way when testing, but feel free to turn it on see it in action. It’s WAY down the page lol; you’ll see:

```
if (indicatedSegment.text == "Jane") {
window.location = "https://www.mikeloucas.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

WAS:

```
let clickedSegment= theWheel.getSegmentAt(e.clientX, e.clientY);

if (clickedSegment) {
       clickedSegment.indicatedSegment = "Jane";
        window.location = "https://www.mikeloucas.com";
        theWheel.draw();
```

IS NOW:

```
    let segmentImage = theWheel.getSegmentAt(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    
      if (segmentImage.text == "Jane") {
      window.location = "https://www.mikeloucas.com";}
            
else if (segmentImage.text == "othername")...{
    }

...theWheel.draw();
```

The trick (for me) was changing "**clickedSegment**" to "**segmentImage**" because "**segmentImage**" was already calling the array of names. I also add an "**ELSE IF**" because I had lots of slices to work work with.

See working thingy here: https://codepen.io/mikeloucas/pen/qBarWoP

My version needs to have the URL and NAME LIST entered twice; it would be cool if someone knows how to do it once (one set instead of two) but maintain both functions of the "CLICK url" and "SPIN url", so I'm still open to advice.

I'd prefer one set over two. :-)